# mysql comparison operators in like query not working

Tags: mysql

I am using the like query to get my expected result, it is working fine until there are no comparison operators in string. Following query is not working for me when there are comparison operators.

```
SELECT * FROM tms_customers WHERE tms_customers.NAME LIKE '%sp<>%^|!@%'
```

but when there are no comparison operators it work

```
SELECT * FROM tms_customers WHERE tms_customers.NAME LIKE '%sp%^|!@%'
```

Help me regarding this query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: why did you remove the `ESCAPE '>'` from your question?

Comment: Works well for me after you removed the `ESCAPE '>'`. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b1JYFtBL1fe5LYRBv9skcd/0

Comment: it was one possible solution, after using ESCAPE '>' it gives me the desired result but it's not giving the desired result when comparison operators are at the end of query string.

Comment: can you explain what you are intending to match/not match with `'%sp<>%^|!@%'`, with examples

Comment: @ysth i have saved 'sp<>%^|!@' in my table and when I try to make a query with like '%sp<>%^|!@%', it returns 0 record.

Comment: @AliHammad There is no problem in having `<` or `>` as value or as part of the `LIKE` operator, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/200291. But most likely you do not have the string `sp<>%^|!@` as such in the database but instead maybe a "html escaped" variant of this where you have the the data stored as `sp&lt;>%^|!@` instead.  Please [edit] your question to include the output of `SELECT NAME, HEX(NAME) FROM tms_customers` so we can see the actual data. After that add a [mcve] which clearly shows that the value is not returned even thou it should.